# basic python script to create a new file with a adhoc name

Tags: python

I'm very new to OOP (python) and i'm just practicing some basic stuff these days. im trying to write a prog that will create a file at a desired location and the file name should not be hardcoded ,it will be passed as an argument to the script.

this is what i'm doing. please tell me where am i going wrong because this creates a file name with the name that i pass in the open function

```
import os
import sys

filename=sys.argv[1]

def create(filename):
    dir='/home/aspx/psharma1/scripts/scripts2'
    x=os.getcwd()
    if x == '/home/aspx/psharma1/scripts':
        os.chdir(dir)
        f=open("filename","w+")
        for i in range(10):
            f.write("this is line %d\r\n" %(i+1))
        f.close()
    else:
        pass

create(filename)
```

Comment: Replace `open("filename","w+")` with `open(filename,"w+")`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) call, which should be:

```
f=open(filename,"w+")
```

Instead of:

```
f=open("filename","w+")
```

This is because `"filename"` is simply the string with the letters "filename", while `filename` means the variable named "filename", and so its content (which in this case is the argument that you passed) will be used as the name of the file.

As a side note, it is recommended that you instead use `open` in the following way:

```
with open(filename, "w+") as f:
    # Do whatever you need with f
```

This is a [context manager](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/), an intuitive but powerful feature in Python that will make sure that the file is correctly closed no matter the errors that may take place during its usage.

Comment: thank you guys... and @jdeshesa - thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @pulkit No problem. Please consider marking the answer as accepted if you think it solved your problem.

Comment: sure i did... but im new here so wont reflect .. will keep coming back though...cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the double quotes around the filename string in the **open** function